# Beginner Compiling from Command Line

Tags: c++

I have just recently purchased the 'Principles of Programming with C++' book and am trying to compile the Hello World program from command line. I have done a little C programming recently and never had any problems building, but now I am getting this big whopping error message. Is there anyone who can parse this?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    //output "Hello, World!" 
    return 0;
}
```

The command I am using to build is `gcc -o helloWorld hello.cpp`

**Error Log :**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-30df63.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-30df63.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-30df63.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-30df63.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in hello-30df63.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently I just needed to use g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: without seeing the code that causes this error, it's unlikely anyone can help.

Comment: The error message by itself isn't that helpful to diagnose the problem. If I had to guess I'd say you are compiling with `clang` and not `clang++`. But nobody can know for sure unless you show your short program and compiler invocation.

Comment: @Austin update your question please, don't just post it in a comment.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. [edit] your question to include all relevant parts.

Comment: Code in comments isn't helpful. Please [edit] your question and add it there, where it can be seen. It's part of the question.

Comment: gcc ? the error message says clang

Comment: Try `g++ -o helloWorld hello.cpp`.

Comment: @Tyker • some platforms (e.g., macOS) soft-link gcc and g++ to clang and clang++.  I'm not in favor of that practice, since I use both clang++ and GNU GCC g++, so I have to ensure I'm using the correct g++ by using its fully qualified path.

Answer (score 3):

> The command I am using to build is gcc -o helloWorld hello.cpp

Use `g++ -o helloWorld hello.cpp`

If you want to use `gcc` to compile it then you can pass flag -`lstdc++` to link with standard library c++, write in console:

Use `gcc -o helloWorld hello.cpp -lstdc++`

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you are compiling C++ source with `clang`, a C compiler. This gives you link editor errors about missing symbols.

Try using `clang++`, a C++ compiler. This should know by default which C++ libraries to link which should solve any missing symbols.

(On MacOS you may have gcc/g++ as frontends for clang/clang++, in which case use `g++`).